# Que tengo mal, no entiendo Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy tratando de desarrollar una webapp en donde se ingrese en este caso el numero de expediente y me muestre la información de esa persona. Busque algunas soluciones dentro de aquí a errores iguales al mio, pero la solución de ellos a mi me sigue sin funcionar.

Este código es el que me ayuda a buscar

```
    function searchData(numExp) {
  
  var sheet = getSpreadSheet(idLibro, nombreHoja);

  var rowsResult = sheet
    .getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
    .getValues()
    .filter(function (row) {
      return row[0] === numExp;
    });

  var firstRow = rowsResult[0];

  var user = {
    numExp: firstRow[0],
    nomPac: firstRow[1],
    cantOx: firstRow[2],
    sat: firstRow[3],
    codPac: firstRow[4],
    coment: firstRow[6],
  };

  var result = JSON.stringify(user);
  return result;
}
```

Y este es el código del formulario

```
function onSuccess(response) {
  
  var user = JSON.parse(response);

  
  document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user.nomPac;
  document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user.cantOx;
  document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user.sat;
  document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user.conPac;
  document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user.coment;

  enableInputs();
}
```

No entiendo que error cometo, solo me muestra el valor de la ultima fila, y yo necesito que me muestro las 5 después de que se le da clic al botón de búsqueda.

Comment: por lo que veo siempre estas reemplazando el mismo div con valores distintos por eso siempre te va a mostrar el ultimo, cada elemento o dato del usuario deberia ir a un elemento distinto del html o concatenarlo.

Comment: probe hacer en un elemento cada dato y me funciono la busqueda, con el codigo motrado crees que me funcionaria poner una tabla para que me muestre en orden los datos?

Comment: si, lo ideal seria mostrar los elementos.

Comment: me podrias brindar algun ejemplo de como  lo podria hacer, he estado intentando y no lo tengo muy claro aun. Te lo agradeceria mucho

Answer (score 0):

Como veo en tu codigo, el problema que tienes es que estas reemplazando el mismo div con datas distintas por eso siempre tu valor sera igual al que dice  `user.coment`

```js
function onSuccess(response) {
  
  var user = JSON.parse(response);

  
  document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user.nomPac;
  document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user.cantOx;
  document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user.sat;
  document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user.conPac;
  document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user.coment;

  enableInputs();
}
```

Basado en lo que quieres que es pintar en una tabla los datos de tu respuesta mas o menos algo asi creo que seria tu solución:

```js
function onSuccess() {
  
  // supongamos que esta es tu data que viene de donde sea que filtres
  const response = {
   "nombre": "Dario",
   "apellido": "Diaas",
   "tel": "78922228"
  }
   
  // 1 - nos traemos la tabla por su ID document.getElementById("table")
  // 2 - escogemos el children que necesitamos .children[3]
  // 3 - reemplazamos el html del children por nuestro valor .innerHTML ='lo que quiereas'
  document.getElementById("table").children[3].innerHTML = `
     <tr>
      <td>${response.nombre}</td>
      <td>${response.apellido}</td>
      <td>${response.tel}</td>
     </tr>
  `;

}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <caption>
    <button onclick="onSuccess()"> 
      Filtrar 
    </button>
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>apellido</th>
      <th>telefono</th>
    <tr/>
  <thead />
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td>Perez</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Carlos</td>
      <td>Noches</td>
      <td>7898</td>
    </tr>
  <tbody />
</table>
```

Espero que te sirva!